# Primary Gmail address

Tags: gmail

Google made me create a new email address and then that became my primary. I want my original Gmail address and I want to get rid of this new one. I am afraid to delete anything because I do not know what it will do to my account or Android. Everything I read is so confusing. Just want my primary to be my original email not the new one.

Comment: You need to tell us more about how "Google made me create a new email address".

Answer (score 1):

So you have an Android phone, maybe a new one? You had to register using a Google account, and you were tricked into registering a new one?

Add your normal Gmail account in the Settings menu. When both Gmail accounts are there, you can delete the first one. Your normal Gmail account will become the primary.